# Adding Items to Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

I may have understood this wrong but looking at the examples found in "Learning Python" by O'Reilly I tried to do the following:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['h']='GG'
>>> d['f']='JJ'
>>> d['h']='PP'
>>> print d
{'h': 'PP', 'f': 'JJ'}
```

Now instead of the 'key' `'h'` having two entries `'GG'` and `'PP'` it only has the last entry, the last one replacing the first one.
I want BOTH in the same key.

```
>>> d['h']+='RR'
>>> print d
{'h': 'PPRR', 'f': 'JJ'}
```

Again this doesn't work, what I wanted was not a concatenated string but comma-separated entires.

I am confused why this does not work.

Comment: I'm am not attacking but asking out of genuine curiosity - why did you believe that `d['h']='PP'` would create a list out of the value that was already there and append the new value to the list?  I'd like to understand how someone new to the language anticipates how the language will work.

Comment: That's ok, I will explain. My python "bible" is Learning python by Mark Lutz and David Ascher. I use that book heavily and its pages 49-51 are really giving me this impression that you can add items to existing keys like that. I am sure they didn't intend to do that but my MULTIPLE reading of those few pages gave me that impression especially the examples. I hope that they include an example like my question in their next edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use-case is handled nicely by the [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) type instead:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['h'].append('GG')
>>> d['f'].append('JJ')
>>> d['h'].append('PP')
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'h': ['GG', 'PP'], 'f': ['JJ']})
```

A *regular* dictionary maps *one* key to *one* value, if you want that value to be a list, then you should make it a list, and append to the list instead.

You don't *have* to use a `defaultdict()` object, you can always make your values explicit lists:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['h'] = ['GG']
>>> d['f'] = ['JJ']
>>> d['h'].append('PP')
>>> print d
{'h': ['GG', 'PP'], 'f': ['JJ']}
```

but now you need to create the lists explicitly. The latter problem can then be circumvented again by using `dict.setdefault()`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('h', []).append('GG')
>>> d.setdefault('f', []).append('JJ')
>>> d.setdefault('h', []).append('PP')
```

which is just a more verbose way of using what `defaultdict()` objects can provide directly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your dictionary to have `'h'` map to a *list* of strings, which you can do as follows:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['f']='JJ'
>>> d['h']=['PP']
>>> d['h'].append( 'RR' )
>>> d
{'h': ['PP', 'RR'], 'f': 'JJ'}
```

If you want all the keys of your dictionary to map to a list (instead of just `'h'`), you can use `collection.defaultdict` as demonstrated in @MartijnPieters's answer.